# How to make an element from a fragment directive?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

From the Chrome DevTools I cannot find any tags to differentiate [this highlighted text segment](https://web.dev/text-fragments/#the-fragment-directive:%7E:text=directive%20is%20a-,mechanism%20for,-URLs%20to%20specify) from the rest text. How can I make the highlighted text(`mechanism for`) an HTML element? Three for [this one](https://github.com/WICG/scroll-to-text-fragment#identifying-a-text-snippet:%7E:text=the%20web%20use-,fragments%20for,-their%20own%20state&text=own%20state/routing.-,These%20pages,-may%20break%20if&text=id%20based%20fragments-,also%20cause,-these%20pages%20to).

More specifically, for illustration, I want to change this HTML snippet:

```
. The fragment directive is a mechanism for URLs to specify instructions directed to the browser rather than the document. It is meant to avoid direct interaction with author script, so that future user agent instructions can be added without fear of introducing breaking changes to existing content. One potential example of such future additions could be translation hints.
```

to this one:

```
. The fragment directive is a <span class="custom_element">mechanism for</span> URLs to specify instructions directed to the browser rather than the document. It is meant to avoid direct interaction with author script, so that future user agent instructions can be added without fear of introducing breaking changes to existing content. One potential example of such future additions could be translation hints.
```

according to the fragment directive: `:~:text=directive%20is%20a-,mechanism%20for,-URLs%20to%20specify`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75201631/how-to-make-an-element-from-a-fragment-directive#:~:text=mechanism%20for works for me (Chrome). You just need a `#` before the `:~:text=`

Comment: No, it does not work. The <code> tag is what I added. @DavidAvikasis

Comment: In an extension you can use chrome.webNavigation.getFrame or various `chrome` events to see the text fragment in a tab's URL. After extracting it you can create find the matching text in your content script using the algorithm defined in the [specification](https://wicg.github.io/scroll-to-text-fragment/), then create the element and put the matched part inside.